# Playing default android sound of button, clicking onTouch() method

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio, ontouchlistener

In my android app I have some buttons, that should work with **onTouch()** method, course I need to change button's text, when finger in ACTION_DOWN position. But this buttons should to play **default** android sound of button clicking (like in onClick() method). Where I can find such sound? I think, it must be in SDK, but how can I find it? And what methods are better for such operation? I'm using MediaPlayer.

Listing:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        addTextShadow(v);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "ACTION_DOWN");
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        clearTextShadow(v);
        isMoved = true;
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "ACTION_MOVE");
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "ACTION_UP");
        if (!isMoved) {
            clearTextShadow(v);
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_new) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "New pressed");

                            playSound(); //MY METHOD TO PLAY SOUND

            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_saved) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Saved pressed");
            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_random) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Random pressed");
            }
        }
        isMoved = false;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And my playSound() method:

```
    public void playSound(){
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
    try {
        mp = MediaPlayer
    .create(MyActivity.this, R.raw.sound); //BUT HERE I NEED DEFAULT SOUND!
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Android play the default click sound by 'default'? At least it does so on ICS.

Comment: Vishwa Patel, no, android plays the default click sound, when we use onClickListener, but not onTouchListener. I test all programms with ICS (SGS2).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use this code in your onTouch() method:

```
view.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
```

If you are simply looking for a preset Android sound then it's better to use this functionality that's provided to you for free by the framework. Doing anything else, unless necessary for customization, would simply result in you working against the framework instead of working with it.

Comment: Vishwa Patel, super! It works, thanx a lot. U r right, playSound() & MediaPlayer are useless now.

Comment: @dmgmyza Excellent! Glad to have helped. You should upvote my answer if you think it's helpful!

Comment: I really want, but my reputation is only 12 now. I need 3 more points to vote up.

Comment: Wow! really cool!The Android SDK is having own set of media files for different purpose like for Click, Navigation UP, Navigation down etc.

Comment: how can i get the click sound if sound settings is off

Comment: its not working in my case , i using this feature at click of linear layout

Comment: yeah worked but please make sure you enable it from settings. Go Setting->sound ->enable touch sound :)

Answer (score 0):

Use default sounds from `/system/media/audio/`

MediaPlayer or SoundPool will help to implement playback.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);`.

It will do both: playing the default sound and vibrate if the user has it enabled in the global settings.