# Playing sound after click on imageview/button

Tags: android, click

I am trying to play click sound on image (ImageView/Button) click and I saw an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915983/playing-default-android-sound-of-button-clicking-ontouch-method?rq=1). I have also tried to use this:

```
profile_pick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            v.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Profile_pic.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2);
        }
    });
```

but it's not working. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

(Adding a raw sound is not a good idea so I would prefer to use a use system sound... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"` to the `profile_pick` . The documentation says that

> The sound effect will only be played if sound effects are enabled by
>   the user, and isSoundEffectsEnabled() is true.

so both the conditions are mandatory. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#playSoundEffect%28int%29) you can find the documentation

Comment: @dev_android i have a same issue. if u resolve this please post your ans Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

```
profile_pick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        AudioManager audioManager = 
        (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK); 
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Profile_pic.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to put your statements inside a block, and in this case the onCreate method.

After that, you initialize the button as variable one, then you use a variable zero and set its onClickListener to an incomplete onClickListener. Use the variable one for the setOnClickListener.

Finally, put the logic to play the sound inside the onClick.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class BasicScreenActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_screen);

        Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
        one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });     
    }
}
```