# Android Things, system sound not working

Tags: button, audio, raspberry-pi3, volume, android-things

I created a simple activity with one button and when I click it Android Things does not reproduce classic click sound.
I installed Android Things dp4_1 on Raspberry Pi 3.
I connect a speaker with 3,5" jack.
I tried to reproduce a sound with TextToSpeech and it works fine, but I can not hear the click button sound.
I also tried to set the max volume with AudioManager

```
AudioManager am =
        (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.setStreamVolume(
        AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,
        am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM),
        0);
```

I have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: I imagine system sounds could have been removed to minimise the android footprint, altho I couldn't find this in the docs

Comment: did you try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917158/4001920