# How to change default ClickSound in whole application from one place

Tags: android, kotlin, button, audio, onclick

Is it possible to change default **ClickSound** in whole android application without needing to implement MediaPlayer in onButtonClickListener/onButtonTouchListener for each button in the app ?

As the application has nearly 20 buttons, it seems to be irrational to implement onButtonClickListenr and play sound in every activity or fragment. It could be great if **we can change the ClickSound in one place for the app.**

Be glad to hear your opinions ...

Comment: check this out maybe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915983/playing-default-android-sound-of-button-clicking-ontouch-method

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
actually think link refers to how enabling default click sound for onTouchMethod and doesn't help me. 
I want to change default click sound for my whole buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension function to face this problem

**ViewExtentions.kt**

```
fun View.setOnClickListenerWithSound(action: () -> Unit) {
    val actionWithSound = ActionWithSound(context, action)

    setOnClickListener {
        actionWithSound.notifyAction()
    }
}

private class ActionWithSound(context: Context,private val action: () -> Unit) {

    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.click )

    fun notifyAction() {
        mediaPlayer.start()
        action.invoke()
    }
}
```

and you can use it as bellow:

```
someBtn.setOnClickListenerWithSound {
        // do what you want
}
```

Comment: I will check the solution and let you know the result.

Comment: in this scenario, I still have to implement setOnClickListenerWithSound  for all of my buttons.
I look forward for just a method to change default android click sound effect ...

Comment: @FarrokhShahriari You must use setOnClickListenerWithSound instead of setOnClickListener ( button with no onClickListener is useless!). Still, if you want to have a button with no onClickListener and have sound, you should create a custom button class and just set an empty setOnClickListenerWithSound in the init of that class.